# Showing that $[H:(K\cap H)] \leq [G:K]$ For $H,K < G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For this problem we want to find a function $\eta: H/(K \cap H) \to G/K$ and show that $\eta$ is well-defined and injective. For this problem we will need to use a result from an earlier part of this problem that says that:

> $\forall g \in G$ $H \cap gK$ is either empty or equal to a coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$: $h(K \cap H), h \in H$

---

For this problem I believe I understand the reasoning behind what we are doing. In that,  $[H:(H\cap K)] \leq [G:K]$ is equivalent to saying that $\lvert H/(H \cap K) \rvert \leq \lvert G/K \rvert$ so by finding a function from $H/(H\cap K)$ to $G/K$ and showing it is well defined and injective then we are showing, by invoking the Pigeonhole Principle, that it cannot be the case that $$\lvert H/(H \cap K) \rvert \gt \lvert G/K \rvert$$ And hence the inequality in the problem statement must be true.

Elements of

1. $H/(K\cap H)$ look like $h(K\cap H) = hK \cap hH = hK \cap H$ for any $h \in H$
2. $G/K$ look like $gK$ for any $g \in G$

First off, I'm having a bit of trouble actually defining my function $\eta$ in that I'm not sure how to write the arbitrary element of $H/(K\cap H)$ that's being taken by $\eta$ to $G/K$. In the first part I found an $a \in H \cap gK$ such that $a = h = gk$ for $h \in H\ \text{and}\ k \in K$ so that $$a(K \cap H) = a(H \cap K) = aH \cap aK = H \cap aK$$ But I'm not quite seeing how this simplifies things.

Also, I've not seen many examples regarding 'well-definedness' but my understanding is that if we have $\eta(a) = a'$ and $\eta(b) = b'$ for $a,b, \in H/(K\cap H)$ then $\eta(ab) = a'b'$. Correct?

Comment: Regarding your commentary: You are right that $[G:H] = |G/H|$. However, I don't believe the pigeonhole principle applies here. Instead, we have a principle from set theory, which states $|A|\leq |B|$ iff $\exists f_{injective}:A\to B$. As for well-definition, usually the argument is to show independence of coset/class representatives (i.e. plug in the same class to $\eta$ with different representatives chosen and show the result of each gives the same coset/class).

Comment: Would this not just be a corollary of the pigeonhole principle though? Since, as I understand it from my text, the Pigeonhole Principle says: "If $A$ and $B$ are sets and $\lvert A \rvert \gt \lvert B \rvert$ then there is no injective function $\sigma: A \to B$. Now, since we have found an injective function $\eta :A \to B$ would that not imply the negation of $\lvert A \rvert \gt \vert B \rvert$? Which would be $\lvert A \rvert \leq \vert B \rvert$

Comment: The property $\eta(ab) = a'b'$ is called "preserving the group operation". "Well-defined" is often kind of vaguely explained. In this case if we want to define $\eta$ by taking a coset $h(H \cap K)$, and then setting the output of $\eta$ to something depending on $h$. When we say $\eta$ is well-defined, that means that the output did not depend on the choice of $h$ for that coset - if another $h$ represents the same coset, it should lead to the same output. (depending on your points of view, this is helpful for showing $\eta$ does preserve the group operation.)

Comment: Some more thoughts about this by a Fields medallist... https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/, https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/welldefined.html. In this case, unless you are given that $K$ is normal, $\eta$ might well not preserve the group operation! If $K$ does happen to be normal then you can deduce something a bit stronger, called "the second isomorphism theorem", which seems to be the inspiration for this question. Also, yes, you could call this the pigeonhole principle, but most mathematicians are happy to accept this fact with no justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating: 
Given two subgroups $H,K\leq G$, we want to show there exists a *well-defined*, *injective* function between the sets of cosets:
$$\eta: H/(H\cap K)\to G/K.$$

---

It can be shown that for any coset of the intersection in $H$, we have:
$$h(H\cap K) = hH\cap hK = H\cap hK.$$
And since $hK$ is a coset of $K$ in $G$, the map suggests itself as:
$$\eta:h(H\cap K)\mapsto hK.$$

---

(i) Suppose $h,h'\in H$ represent the same coset. Then $h(H\cap K) = h'(H\cap K)$. Multiplying by the inverse on the left yields:
$$H\cap K = (h^{-1}h')(H\cap K)$$
Hence $h^{-1}h'\in H\cap K$ and in particular, $h^{-1}h'\in K$. It follows then that $K = (h^{-1}h')K$. So that finally multiplying by $h$ again gives:
$$hK = h'K.$$
This gives well-definition of $\eta$. $\square$
*Thanks to Izaak for the assist here!*

---

(ii) Suppose for $h,h'\in H$ that:
$$hK = h'K.$$
Then intersecting both sides with $H$, we get the middle equality:
$$h(H\cap K) = hH\cap hK = H\cap hK \text{ }(=)\text{ } H\cap h'K = h'H\cap h'K = h'(H\cap K),$$
from which it follows that
$$h(H\cap K) = h'(H\cap K).$$
Hence $\eta$ is injective. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the answer. Regarding the concept of well-definition, what exactly is the underlying principle behind it, regardless of the domain/range of the function? Is it to show that each input cannot map to more than one output? Hence, the function is a function. Or, equivalently, how should I go about thinking how to show a function is well-defined regardless of the domain/range?

Comment: I think you're overthinking well-definedness - if $H_1 \le H_2 \le G$, then whenever $gH_1 = g' H_1$, we have $gH_2 = g' H_2$, using the fact that $gH = g'H \iff g^{-1} g' \in H$. Apply this to $H_1 = H \cap K$ and $H_2 = K$.

Comment: At NumericalDisintegration I defer to Izaak's comment above to answer here. @IzaakvanDongen I tried multiplying by $h^{-1}$ earlier, but went through with the distribution instead and got stuck haha. Thank thee